# Android: Add delay between the in and out animation of ViewAnimator

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, viewanimator

I'm simply trying to animate my view transaction using a ViewAnimator.

But I want my view to slide out and in from the SAME side.

Since the in and out animation happen at the same time, how can I add a delay between the in and out animation so my in transaction appear nicely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use this in ur animation xml :

```
android:startOffset = "x"
```

It means that your animation will start after x milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is perfect but can by complicated if using a ViewAnimator, after doing some test and more research, I finally found a VERY simple way. I ended up by adding android:startOffset in the XML animation. This way the animation wait the desired amount of time before starting.

Exemple:

If the slide out duration is set to 500ms, then set the startOffset of the slide in to 500ms.

Slide_in_from_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" android:startOffset="[Replace with fade out duration]" />
</set>
```